# How can I get single node data using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have the following xml file

```
<categories>
  <category>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Computer</name>
    <description>Information tech.</description>
    <active>True</active>
  </category>
  <category>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Cate1</name>
    <description>MMukh</description>
    <active>True</active>
  </category>
</categories>
```

---

I need to get one category data specify by id value and store them in textboxes.
Could you please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) like

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.XML");
var item = xDoc.Descendants("category")
               .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Element("id").Value == "1");
if(item == null)
   return;

string Name = item.Element("name").Value;
string Decription = item.Element("description").Value;
string active = item.Element("active").Value;
```

You can assign the results to your TextBoxes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Linq To Xml and converting the elements to a `Dictionary<string,string>`?

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
int id=1;

var dict = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//category[id=" + id + "]")
            .Elements()
            .ToDictionary(e=>e.Name.LocalName , e=>(string)e);

Console.WriteLine(dict["description"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply deserialize given XML in object and apply LINQ to Objects. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Load it first with XDocument

```
XDocument test = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
```

then,

```
    var qry = (from item in test.Descendants("category")
      where item.Element("id").Value == 1
      select new
      {
         Name = (string)test.Element("name").Value
         Description = (string)test.Element("description").Value
         Active = (string)test.Element("active").Value
      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This created an anonymous type and you can now display your data like this:

```
if (qry != null) {
Console.WriteLine(qry.Name);
Console.WriteLine(qry.Description);
Console.WriteLine(qry.Active);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlDataString);

var categoryElement = xml.Root
    .Elements("category")
    .FirstOrDefault(e => (string)e.Element("id") == "1");
```